# API get request from URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, get, request

I am new to using APIs and also HTTP GET Requests.

How can I use send a GET Request to an API url in order to fill in an HTML wire frame using the information received from the GET request?

From sources viewed online I believe some AJAx/Jquery is required...I am unsure

Sorry I have not provided code but I am unsure as to where to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reading jQuery documentation about jQuery.ajax():
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

In this case you might only need to do GET request so checkout jQuery.get() first:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

If the response format is JSON then you can even use shorthand jQuery.getJSON():
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

After reading through these docs, I'm pretty sure you will know how to begin coding.